# Installing Autodesk Inventor 11 Pro on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, autodesk-inventor

I have a new computer with 64-bit Win 7 and I would like to install Inventor 11. Does anyone have some experience with it? I know it is an ancient version, but people claim they made it work.

I tried installing Inventor without compatibility mode and it stops at the Pre-installation checks window. It detects unsupported version of Windows there. I've googled the problem and there are basically two kinds of answers:

- Autodesk's official position is "It's not compatible, period - get a newer version"
- Various people claim they made it work quite normally, but they don't describe the procedure.

All I get is that simply installing in Compatibility mode for WinXP doesn't guarantee the program to work.

I know that WinXP Mode (virtualized XP) should solve the problem, but it also poses a new problem since there's only a generic graphic card in Virtual environment and I need 3D acceleration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Drill down to the *inventor setup.exe* file in the `bin\` directory on the cd and it will not run the os detection and will install just fine.  That's not saying that the program will run flawlessly once installed.

Answer (score 1):

Inventor11 runs on windows7 in compatibility mode. Only the installation has a problem:it must to install WITHOUT the content center because it is based on win2000 and not accepted in win7. I tried to install the program in different methods, it was succesful on win7 32 bit and without content center. The only thing is strange that we have problem with the videocard despite of it is an nVidia 3450/4000 SDI card: there are strange shadows appear on the drawing area when we work with assemblies. The Pc is a Dell workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Once you install it in compatibility mode, navigate to the program folder where the program executable(s) reside, and do the compatibility setting for that file(s) also.

Comment: Thanks. I have to ask, tho - is this based on your experience with installing Inventor 11 on Win7 or are you guessing? I have seen forum posts describing trying exactly that but the poster reports Inventor doesn't work flawlessly.

Comment: Its an educated guess, but if you don't want my help just say so.

Comment: There's no need to feel offended. First: if you're referring to Windows XP compatibility mode, I specifically stated that I would like to avoid this. The graphic card in virtualized mode is generic, providing only basic 2D graphics whereas Autodesk Inventor needs 3D support. Second, if you're referring to compatibility settings in executable's properties - I have already tried this and it doesn't work. The setup program checks the platform and it detects unsupported version of Windows. Regardless of compatibility settings. Anyway, thanks for helping. I'd appreciate if you've any other idea.